# Fabric manual integration with react-native-firebase on iOS

Tags: xcode, react-native, crashlytics, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to manually integrate fabric and crashlytics into my react native iOS project without using CocoaPods following this guide: 
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/crashlytics/ios

#### Steps I've taken so far

I've added the Fabric and Crashlytics library to my project. They are in a folder called Firebase, the rest of the Firebase framework is working.

[image: Folder Structure]

2. I've added the run phase script.

[image: Run Phase]

But I still get this error:

[image: Error]

Below are my header and framework search paths.

Header search paths:
[image: Header search paths]

Framework search paths:
[image: Framework search paths]

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions for manual integration have been merged into the react-native-firebase docs:

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-docs/blob/master/docs/crashlytics/ios.md